# Copy href from <a> inside a DIV with unique id and paste somewhere else in that DIV

Tags: jquery, href

I am trying to find a way to copy the href from the `data-name="entity_field_post_title"` div, and use it as the href of `data-type="image"` div

The goal behind this is to open the corresponding link of the page instead of opening it's photos. These are miniatures of posts, and I would like to open the post themselves, not the photos.

Important to point out that the top div's `ID` number changes each time unpredictably.

```
<div id="drts-content-post-1163">
    <div class="drts-display-element-columns-3">
        <div class="drts-row drts-gutter-none">
            <div class="slick-list draggable">
                <div class="slick-track">
                    <div data-type="image" class="slick-slide">
                        <a href="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/horse.jpeg" ><figure><img src="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/horse.jpeg"></figure></a>
                    </div>
                    <div data-type="image" class="slick-slide">
                        <a href="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/panda.png" ><figure><img src="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/panda.png"></figure></a>
                    </div>
                </div>          
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-name="column" class="drts-display-element-column-6">
            <div class="drts-row drts-gutter-none">
                <div data-name="entity_field_post_title" class="directory-listing-title ">
                    <a href="http://localhost/wp/anuncios/prueba-desde-backend-1/" target="_self" class="drts-entity-1163">TEXT</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've left the selectors as variables just in case you need to make minor changes to those, but the base works - Looping through every `containerDiv`, getting the href from `linkDiv > <a>`, and applying that link to every `imageDiv > <a>`

```js
let containerDiv = 'div[id*="drts-content-post-"]';
let linkDiv = 'div[data-name="entity_field_post_title"]';
let imageDiv = 'div[data-type="image"]';

let $container = $(containerDiv).has(linkDiv);

$container.each((index, element) => {
  let link = $(element).find(`${linkDiv} > a`).attr('href');
  $(element).find(`${imageDiv} > a`).attr('href', link);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="drts-content-post-1163">
    <div class="drts-display-element-columns-3">
        <div class="drts-row drts-gutter-none">
            <div class="slick-list draggable">
                <div class="slick-track">
                    <div data-type="image" class="slick-slide">
                        <a href="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/horse.jpeg" ><figure><img src="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/horse.jpeg"></figure></a>
                    </div>
                    <div data-type="image" class="slick-slide">
                        <a href="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/panda.png" ><figure><img src="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/panda.png"></figure></a>
                    </div>
                </div>          
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-name="column" class="drts-display-element-column-6">
            <div class="drts-row drts-gutter-none">
                <div data-name="entity_field_post_title" class="directory-listing-title ">
                    <a href="http://localhost/wp/anuncios/prueba-desde-backend-1/" target="_self" class="drts-entity-1163">TEXT</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code from before was a simplified version of my code.  In reality there are some other containers inbetween which `let $container = $('div').has('.div-good-one');` points to. I believe I need an AND condition to be able to target the container with both type of DIV inside. How should I do that?

Comment: That depends on what the structure is inside your code - the .has() method can be chained however, so you could add additional checks for classes / IDs if you can. Otherwise, it would be helpful to post the additional code so that it's easier for us to see what can be done

Comment: Yes, I could chain it, I can find the classes or IDs to do it. Should I chain it like this? `let $container = $('div').has('.another-div').has('.div-good-one');`

Comment: Still trying to add it. I am working in a Wordpress and I am having some troubles adding the function to the functions.php file which calls the js file! :/

Comment: Error messages? You see any changes in the HTML?

Comment: No error messages, no changes in HTML. I added an alert and JS is being imported in wordpress successfully. I am currently changing your code trying different things, but no results yet. Maybe is some ' or " not written as it should?

Comment: I don't know, the snippet I posted seems to work as intended, so I would assume the issues are with the adjustments to the complete code; Not much more I can do to help without seeing that code

Comment: I edited my original post with the simplified version of my code (removed CSS and empty DIVs). Maybe it helps! :D

Comment: Cheers; I'll edit my post in a bit when I've had a look

Comment: What you wrote makes sense, I checked the conditions and they all look fine to me but it is still not changing the href and not changing the HTML in any way. Everything works fine though.  Could it be that the image is pushing again the href to its `a` after the JS code has loaded?

Comment: Might be worth getting some console logs inside my code - `console.log($(element).find(`${imageDiv} > a`).attr('href'))` as the last line of the each should make sure it's ran

Comment: script_substitute_a_photos.js?ver=1.0.0:8 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at script_substitute_a_photos.js?ver=1.0.0:8
(anonymous) @ script_substitute_a_photos.js?ver=1.0.0:8

Comment: Sounds like you don't have jQuery installed

Comment: Strange, I do have `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wp/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wp/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1'></script>` in the header

Comment: Unsure of how WordPress handles imports, but you could try `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` instead

Comment: jquery is up and running. I checked it with a if(jQuery) inside the .js file. I have added your version just in case. The console keeps telling me there is some syntax error in line 23: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list. Line 23 is ´ let link = $(element).find(${linkDiv} > a).attr('href'); ´

Comment: `let link = $(element).find(\`${linkDiv} > a\`).attr('href')`

Comment: Hey! It works!!! this terminology: `${linkDiv}` was not working so I changed each one for the information above and it did work :) I will post the solution below. **Thank you very much!**

Comment: No worries, glad we got there! :D

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand but if you just want to make the picture into a link you can use an anchor-tag with a background picture like this:

```
<a class="photo" href="website.net/link" title="photo" id="photo">photo</a>
```

Comment: No @Gandalfion.  Let me try to explain myself again.  I need to substitute the current hrefs of class="div1" in order to  "#1163 .div1 a href = #1163 .div-good-one a href "  and  "#734 .div1 a href = #734 .div-good-one a href " and repeat that for every other #id in the page (there are many).

Comment: You want the href of the imgage `a` tags to be the same as the href of the `.div-good-one`, for each div container?

Comment: exactly! (for each container with different id)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Light the solution was found.
First part is to detect whether JS and jQuery was working in Wordpress.

```
// Select all the top level divs, without using ID

alert("JS works");
if (jQuery) {  
  alert('Jquery Loaded');
} else {
  alert('Jquery Not Loaded');
}
```

This is how jQuery is set in Wordpress because the $ is set as a function otherwise. I created "linko" to understand what was happening inside the `.find()`

```
// jQuery code:
jQuery( function( $ ){

  // Safely use the $ alias here
  // Code here will be executed on the document.ready event
  let containerDiv = 'div[id*="drts-content-post-"]';
  let linkDiv = 'div[data-name="entity_field_post_title"]';
  let imageDiv = 'div[data-type="image"]';

  let $container = $(containerDiv).has(linkDiv);

  $container.each((index, element) => {
    let link = $(element).find(`div[data-name="entity_field_post_title"] > a`).attr('href');
    console.log(link);
    let linko = $(element).find(`div[data-type="image"] > a`).attr('href');
    console.log(linko);

    $(element).find(`div[data-type="image"] > a`).attr('href', link);
    console.log($(element).find(`div[data-type="image"] > a`).attr('href'));
  })
});
```